# Problem with protecting admin routes e.g. Uncaught type error

Tags: angular

I wanted to protect admin routes in my web application. I created an admin-auth-guard service and used canActivate()(I had problems but I fixed it with reference to A previous thread). Now during the time of compiling no error popped up but in realtime, the console popped up some error messages:
[image: Console Error Message]
Here is my admin auth guard service code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Thank You for any help.

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: you pasted wrong code sample in your code snippet, could you provide admin-auth-guard-service.ts code?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. I am new to Stack Overflow and a beginner in programming. Thanks in advance... I have updated the question please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630650/problem-with-protecting-admin-routes-with-angular-8-and-firebase?noredirect=1#comment103571874_58630650